# vector push back clarifying

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, push-back

I can't figure out how `push_back(const value_type& val)` exactly works, in [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) it says about `val` that

`val is Value to be copied (or moved) to the new element ...`

1. How it can be copied when it takes `val` by reference ?
2. Will that copying ever call the copy constructor of `val` ?

and what's exactly happening here ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>    
using namespace std;    
struct x
{
    x(int v = 0) : v(v) {}
    int v;
};    
vector<vector<x>> parts;    
void fillParts()
{
    vector<x> values = { x(1), x(2), x(3) };
    parts.push_back(values);
}        
int main()
{
    fillParts();  
    parts[0][0].v = -123;
    cout << parts[0][0].v;    // -123
    return 0;
}
```

this runs with no erros,
is `parts[0]` is a reference to local vector `values` or a copy ?
if it is a reference shouldn't it at least give some warnings saying that your accessing and modifying local objects of freed stack ?

Comment: Values are copied using the copy constructor, the `parts` vector copies the `values` vector when doing the `push_back`, so when accessing them they are not freed. The local variable `values` was indeed freed but a copied vector with the same underlaying data is stored in 'parts`.

Comment: @JavierMr yeah but `push_back` takes by reference - then how it perform copying of `values` vector ?

Comment: @ampawd Why not? `Copy Constructor` takes by reference in general and it performs copying perfectly.

Comment: I think compiler may optimize the code to use 
`void push_back (value_type&& val);` and you will have move assignment operator in action. Anyway, it will be either copy or moved entity. Actually, you can debug it with F11.

Comment: @Yola hmm that sounds interesting, but moving is a c++11 feature, in previous standard it won't do that

Comment: So you will have a copy. And forget about my words about debugging, because in debug builds compiler probably will not use such optimization.

Comment: @Yola there is no "optimization" for push_back with an lvalue to actually match rvalue parameter. The author would have to write `std::move`.  There are better approaches.

Comment: @M.M thanks for pointing this out, after some testing i also think so, at least because silent moving would be undesirable in case the user wants destructor to be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How it can be copied when it takes val by reference?

Think of a *copy constructor.*
It takes parameter by reference, and it performs copying perfectly.

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(const Bar & rhs); // by reference, to copy.
};
```

> Will that copying ever call the copy constructor of val ?

Copy operation uses copy constructor.

You can actually see if it's copied, or moved by providing user-defined constructors.

```
struct x
{
public:
    x(const x & rhs)
    {
        // Some copy operation.
        std::cout << "Copied" << std::endl;
    }

    x(x && rhs)
    {
        // Some move operation.
        std::cout << "Moved" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: note: for `struct x` as in the question, you'll want to actually perform the copy of the member variable in those constructors!

Comment: is `vector` copy constructor looks something like this `vector<T>(const vector<T>& rhs)` ?

Comment: @ampawd You're being confused between constructor of `x` and `std::vector`. Now, you're looking at the other(or wrong) side of this copying operation. You're calling `push_back`, (not constructor)

Comment: @DeanSeo No I actually got what youre saying, ... just to clarify things

Comment: @DeanSeo and in my example copy ctor of vector also will be called because `parts[0]` is a vector

Comment: @ampawd You're right. Your `std::vector` takes another `std::vector`, so yes it invokes its copy constructor since `push_back` is copy-based. (And it makes sense! You don't want `push_back` to *move* a given argument, because you'll maybe still want to use that object.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    A(const A&) { cout << "copy cons" << endl; }
    A& operator= (A &&) { cout << "move" << endl; };
    A& operator= (const A &) { cout << "copy" << endl; };
};
vector<A> parts;
void fillParts()
{
    A a;
    parts.push_back(a);
}
int main()
{
    fillParts();
    return 0;
}
```

I got copy cons called in both debug and release builds.